# C Game of life issues

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to code game of life in C. I have been sitting for 7 hours wondering on how to solve it. I have come far, but there is something which is making the code not work as it should. I believe I have done something wrong between the next and current variables in the structure. Maybe wrong in counting if neighbor is alive or dead. Anyhow, I would appreciate any help!

```
void checkField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {
    int neighborCount;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                neighborCount = getNeighborCount(rows, cols, r, c, field);
                nextGeneration(rows, cols, r, c, neighborCount, field);
        }
    }
}

int getNeighborCount(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    int neighborCount = 0;

    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r - 1, c - 1, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r - 1, c, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r - 1, c + 1, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r, c - 1, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r, c + 1, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r + 1, c - 1, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r + 1, c, field);
    neighborCount += checkNeighbors(rows, cols, r + 1, c + 1, field);

    return neighborCount;
}


int checkNeighbors(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    int neighborAlive;

    if (r < 0 || r > rows || c < 0 || c > cols || field[r][c].current != ALIVE){
        return neighborAlive = 0;
    }
    else {
        return neighborAlive = 1;
    }
}

void nextGeneration(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, int neighborCount, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    for (int r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++) {
        for (int c = 0 ; c < cols ; c++) {
            field[r][c].current = DEAD;
            field[r][c].next = DEAD;
        }
    }

    if (neighborCount < 2){
        field[r][c].current = DEAD;
        field[r][c].next = DEAD;
    }

    if (neighborCount == 2 || neighborCount == 3) {
        field[r][c].current = ALIVE;
        field[r][c].next = ALIVE;

    }

    if ((field[r][c].current == DEAD) && neighborCount == 3) {
        field[r][c].current = ALIVE;
        field[r][c].next = ALIVE;
    }

    if (neighborCount >= 4) {
        field[r][c].current = DEAD;
        field[r][c].next = DEAD;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @Cows42 don't remove the question because future users will not be able to relate answers to the question :)

Comment: how does a "debug my code" question with a big code dump and without a clear statement of the issue gets so many upvotes?

Comment: @bolov I clearly stated where I thought the issues were. Apparently I was right on both. "I believe I have done something wrong between the next and current variables in the structure. Maybe wrong in counting if neighbor is alive or dead."

Comment: Please, post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve example, not code excerpts, as you can hide the problem in part of the cut code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the conditional in the `checkNeighbors()` function is working, you have a few problems in the way you are updating from one generation to the next. In the function `nextGeneration()`, you don't need to clear the array of cells, because you are about to overwrite the next generation anyway. And in each of the tests in this function, you have, e.g.:

```
if (neighborCount < 2){
    field[r][c].current = DEAD;
    field[r][c].next = DEAD;
}
```

But you only need `field[r][c].next = DEAD;`. This is your new `nextGeneration()` function:

```
void nextGeneration(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, int neighborCount, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    if (neighborCount < 2)
        field[r][c].next = DEAD;

    if (neighborCount == 2 || neighborCount == 3) 
        field[r][c].next = ALIVE;

    if ((field[r][c].current == DEAD) && neighborCount == 3)
        field[r][c].next = ALIVE;

    if (neighborCount >= 4)
        field[r][c].next = DEAD;
}
```

Then, at the end of the `checkField()` function, you need to copy the next generation into the current generation. This is your new `checkField()` function:

```
void checkField(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    int neighborCount;
    int r, c;

    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                neighborCount = getNeighborCount(rows, cols, r, c, field);
                nextGeneration(rows, cols, r, c, neighborCount, field);
        }
    }
    /* Now, copy next generation into current */
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            field[r][c].current = field[r][c].next;
}
```

With these changes, your code works for me, although I think that there might be a problem with your rules. I tried the glider, and it doesn't behave the way that I expected. Here is what the grid looks like at the second generation:

```
. . X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
X . X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. X X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
X X X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

## Spoiler Alert:

Here is an updated `nextGeneration()` function with rules that correctly implement Conway's Game of Life. Your original rules were regenerating dead cells with only 2 neighbors.

```
void nextGeneration(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, int neighborCount, cell field[rows][cols]) {

    if (field[r][c].current == ALIVE) {
        if ((neighborCount < 2) || (neighborCount > 3)){
            field[r][c].next = DEAD;
        } else {
            field[r][c].next = ALIVE;
        }
    } else {
        if (neighborCount == 3) {
            field[r][c].next = ALIVE;
        } else {
            field[r][c].next = DEAD;
        }
    }
}
```

## Update:

After all of the above, I now see that you were trying to flip the display back and forth between the current and next generations. This complicates the update logic, since you have to alternate between generations here too. The bottom line is that this code is just more complicated than it needs to be. You can implement this the way that you wanted to, but there were still many update issues causing problems, and your main loop in `main()` was failing to alternate between generations. You can keep the changes that I suggest, and remove all references to `printCurrentField` and `printNextField`. This lets you simplify the function `printField()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int checkNeighbors(const int rows, const int cols, 
    int r, int c, cell field[rows][cols]) {
    int neighborAlive;

    if (r < 0 || r > rows || c < 0 || c > cols || field[r][c].current != ALIVE){
        return neighborAlive = 0;
    }
    else {
        return neighborAlive = 1;
    }
}
```

Suppose `rows` is 7. That means that there are seven rows. But this code will access eight rows: zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, and seven. That can't be right.

Comment: rows is a constant set to 20? From my understanding, the if function will check if the 'r' or 'c' variable is out of boundary. Should they be so, then it simply adds 0 to the counter which does not affect anything.

Comment: `(r < 0 || r > rows || c < 0 || c > cols || field[r][c].current != ALIVE` I would double check these conditions in a debugger

Comment: @Cows42 If you read my answer, I explain why it doesn't do that. If rows is set to 20, that means there are 20 rows. But this test will allow 21 rows. (Count them.)

Comment: Sorry, I recently started learning C. How do you perform what you ask? Or do you mean that I write simple code and test the conditions?

Comment: Do you understand the code you pasted? I'm trying to figure out what you know and what you don't know so that I can give you a useful answer. How many different values of `r` do you think will satisfy that `if`? How many rows do you think there are? Are these numbers equal? Should they be?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe I understand the issue. In the conditions I included the 0 and the 20. Then I think this would solve it?

Comment: r < 0 || r >= rows || c < 0 || c >= cols || field[r][c].current != ALIVE

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I adjusted the conditions to the one above. So that should correct the issue 0-19 = 20 rows. However, it's still not outputting the correct values on second screen. Perhaps there are other issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
void loadCustom(const int rows, const int cols, cell field[rows][cols]) {

  printf("Give custom format string: ");
  do {
    int r, c;
    scanf("%d,%d", &r, &c);
    field[r][c].current = ALIVE;
  } while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

scanf returns value try to FIX sig seg fault after bad input , I suppose to better comment code and use valgrind . Memory management is bad so you are going out of array I think there is a problem try to check it manualy